# Running Webkit engine on the Application level

Tags: android, webkit, android-browser

I've got several Activities, that need to access JS code, running in WebView. I need that JS code and it's state to be accessible from everywhere, so I was thinking maybe I can run Webkit engine in my application class, and supply data from it to webview and to other components of my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about moving all general accessible state to a javascript interface in java which you register using the javascript bridge:

```
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsBridge(), "jsbridge");
```

I use this to transfer data from javascript to my android/java code and back. It doesn't offer a generic interface to access all data but maybe that's still sufficient.

Comment: I already have it, but I'll need to pull all code from one webview and then load it into another. I was thinking about global JS engine, accessible from every part of application.